# what is the value of $\theta$ used in calculate volume bounded by $z=x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2=2x$

Tags: calculus, integration

This is an example from my textbook, it explain everything well except the reason why $\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{-\pi}{2}$ but not $2\pi < \theta < 0$. It's not explained and I can't understand the reason.

[image]

Comment: Is this a question from Riley-Hobson-Bence, mathematical methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: if $r$ is the radius, it must be nonnegative. Hence $\cos\theta$ is nonegative ($r=2\cos\theta$), i.e. $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Figure 9. If $r$ is always nonnegative, then for what angles $\theta$ can we find a point $(r, \theta)$ in polar coordinates that lies in the orange circle? Notice that the circle lies in Quadrants I and IV only. Indeed, these are the only two quadrants where $r = 2\cos\theta$ is positive.